# R using rbind with a name that is from another variable

Tags: r

If I make a matrix like so;

```
m<-matrix(1,dimnames=list('row','column'))
```

```
    column
row      1
```

I can add a new row like so with rbind

```
m<-rbind(m,row2=2)
```

```
     column 
row       1 
row2      2
```

But... if I have a string variable like

```
tag<-"row3"
```

Why can't I used rbind as

```
m<-rbind(m,tag=3)
```

where row3 should be and not tag as

```
     column
row       1
row2      2
tag       3
```

but want

```
     column
row       1
row2      2
row3      3
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can do this , by creating a matrix with right dimnames

```
m <- matrix(1,dimnames=list('row','column'))
m <- rbind(m,row2=2)
tag <- "row3"
m <- rbind(m,matrix(3,dimnames=list(tag,'column')))

m
     column
row       1
row2      2
row3      3
```

Comment: I think he wants the rowname as row3 not tag, and 3 as value.

Comment: @Hemmo Thanks. I change my answer.

Comment: @Hemmo maybe nice but I find it tricky! actually I would use your solution in the comment.

Comment: Ags and Hem, thanks for your answers, both work and save me time

Answer (score 4):

You could just use `rbind` without naming the new row, and then use `rownames` to name that row:

```
m <- rbind(m,3)
rownames(m)[3]<-tag
```

Some benchmarking between this and @agstudy's solution:

```
m <- matrix(1,dimnames=list('row','column'))
m <- rbind(m,row2=2)
tag <- "row3"

fn1<-function(m,tag){
  m <- rbind(m,matrix(3,dimnames=list(tag,'column')))
  m
}

fn2<-function(m,tag){
  m <- rbind(m,3)
  rownames(m)[3]<-tag
  m
}
library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(fn1(m,tag),fn2(m,tag))
Unit: microseconds
        expr    min     lq median     uq    max neval
 fn1(m, tag)  4.665  5.598  6.065  6.532 15.862   100
 fn2(m, tag) 11.663 13.062 13.063 13.530 48.517   100
```

Comment: I would also do this my way, although your method seems to be slightly faster: microbenchmark gives 6 microseconds versus 13 ;)

Answer (score 2):

Since `substitute()` [does not process function arguments](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2002-January/018135.html), the only way to emulate a dynamic variable name in this case would be `eval(parse(...))`:

```
> m <- eval(parse(text=paste("rbind(m,",tag,"=3)")))
> m
     column
row       1
row2      2
row3      3
```

It is freaky, and I would not recommend it, but I post it for completeness.